# Unable to process binding in devextreme / knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, devextreme

I have another function that calls the `"GetEmployee" function from the server and when I check the call in the Chrome Debugger I can see my details coming through as expected so it's not a server side error.

However, if I place a breakpoint on the third line of `quickBookingSource` the breakpoint is never reached. I do have `quickBooking:quickBookingSource` in the viewModel definition and there are no typos.

Also, you'll see I have added a ternary operator with "blah" text as the safety net but to no avail

The error message I'm getting is:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return project }"
Message: project is not defined
```

Code is:

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="dxTileView: {listHeight:tileWidgetHeight,itemClickAction:sendProject,baseItemHeight: 80, baseItemWidth: 100,dataSource:quickBooking}">
            <div data-options="dxTemplate : { name:'item' }" class="tile">
                <h2 data-bind="text: project"></h2>
                <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
                <p data-bind="text: costCenter"></p>
                <p>Jetzt Büchen</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var quickBookingSource = DevExpress.data.createDataSource({
        load: function (loadOptions) {
            if (loadOptions.refresh) {
                var deferred = new $.Deferred();
                callService("GetEmployee",
                    {
                        employeeNo: aktivEmployee.id
                    },
                function (result) {
                    var mapped = $.map(result, function (data) {
                        return {
                            name: data.LastNProjects? data.LastNProjects["Name"]:"blah",
                            project: data.LastNProjects? data.LastNProjects["Address"]:"blah",
                            costCenter: data.LastNCostCenters? data.LastNCostCenters["Name"]:"blah"
                        }
                    });
                    deferred.resolve(mapped);
                });
                return deferred.promise();
            }
        },
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: At a quick glance is project property an observable?  Does the data from quickBookingSource get put into an observable on the main ViewModel thats bound to the HTML?

Comment: @William project is not an observable. I have mostly copied the code from a tilewidget from another view in the same project which is working fine.

Comment: the error sounds like KO is looking for an observable named project on your VM bound to the UI and cant find it.  What does your viewmodel look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your case in the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/7aSS7/.

Request to server is mocked with setTimeout.
You can click Refresh button to reload dataSource. The demo shows that your code works correctly. It seems that problem is in client code behind the scene if server code is ok.

```
<div class="dx-viewport dx-theme-ios dx-version-major-6 dx-theme-ios-typography">
    <div data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Refresh', clickAction: reloadData }"></div>
    <span data-bind="visible: loading">Loading ...</span>
    <div data-bind="dxTileView: { listHeight: tileWidgetHeight, itemClickAction: sendProject, baseItemHeight: 200, baseItemWidth: 100, dataSource: quickBooking }">
        <div data-options="dxTemplate : { name:'item' }" class="tile">
            <h2 data-bind="text: project"></h2>
            <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
            <p data-bind="text: costCenter"></p>
            <p>Jetzt Büchen</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

// stub service call
var callService = function(method, data, success) {
    var fakeData = [
        { LastNProjects: { Name: 'test project1' }, LastNCostCenters: { Name: 'cost center1' }},
        { LastNProjects: { Name: 'test project2' }, LastNCostCenters: { Name: 'cost center2' }},
        { LastNProjects: { Name: 'test project3' }, LastNCostCenters: { Name: 'cost center3' }},
        { LastNProjects: { Name: 'test project4' }, LastNCostCenters: { Name: 'cost center4' }}
    ];

    setTimeout(function() { 
        success(fakeData);
    }, 1500);
};

var quickBookingSource = DevExpress.data.createDataSource({
    load: function (loadOptions) {
        vm.loading(true);
        if (loadOptions.refresh) {
            var deferred = new $.Deferred();
            callService("GetEmployee",
                        {
                            employeeNo: 'id'
                        },
                        function (result) {
                            var mapped = $.map(result, function (data) {
                                return {
                                    name: data.LastNProjects? data.LastNProjects["Name"]:"blah",
                                    project: data.LastNProjects? data.LastNProjects["Address"]:"blah",
                                    costCenter: data.LastNCostCenters? data.LastNCostCenters["Name"]:"blah"
                                }
                            });
                            deferred.resolve(mapped);
                            vm.loading(false);
                        });
            return deferred.promise();
        }
    },
});


var vm = {

    loading: ko.observable(false),

    reloadData: function() {
        quickBookingSource.load();
    },

    tileWidgetHeight: 300,

    quickBooking: quickBookingSource,

    sendProject: function(args) {
        console.log("send " + args.itemData.name);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Oh... pants. In order to make the code readable as possible for ye guys I shortened some of the HTML where the error was. I had double quotes within double quotes in the databind string. I'm an idiot. Thanks for everyone's time